# WCF client method

Tags: wcf

I am having a very strange issue on my WCF client method.

My client proxy did work quite well with a method:

```
QuoteResult result = proxy.GetQuote(param);
```

But after I made some changes to the WCF (Only database access codes), after I updated my client proxy, I have to use code in my client:

```
GetQuoteRequest request = new GetQuoteRequest(param);
QuoteResultDetail result =  proxy.GetQuote(request).GetQuoteResult;
```

Can anyone tell me what's been changed in WCF service side or what caused this?

Comment: It may be caused by a model changed, if you use the same objects in your WCF contract / service and your database model.

Comment: Yes, thanks Rom.  I found out this was caused by model. But I still cannot understand this affects the way that client calls the ws.

Comment: Can you post your service contract and one or two objects of your model ? I will post an detailed answer.